# Why "error_message" don't show error ActiveRecord validate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Im worked on a project that create events.But I click on a "create event" button with empty fields partial "_error_messages" don't render list with a errors.The page the page is loaded again.Validates seems to be working, in rails console I tried to create and bash show me an error "can't be blank".
This is my _event_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for event, html: { class: "event-form" } do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages', event: event %>
<% unless current_user %>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-md-4'>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
          <%= label :email, "Введите Ваш email:" %>
          <%= text_field_tag :email, "",class: "form-control" %>
          <small>Он нужен для того, что бы Вы могли позже отредактировать добавленное Вами событие.</small>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-8">

      <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
        <%= f.label "Название" %>

        <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control"  %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
        <%= f.label "Изображение" %>
        <%= image_tag event.image, class: "img-responsive" if event.image.present? %>
        <%= f.file_field :image %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
        <%= f.label "Город" %><br />
        <%= select_tag :city_id, options_from_collection_for_select(City.all, :id, :name), name: "event[city_id]", placeholder: "Город" %>
        <%#= f.file_field :image %>
      </div>



      <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
        <%= f.label "Описание" %>
        <%= f.text_area :description, class: "form-control", rows: 10  %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
        <%= f.label "Адрес" %>
        <%= f.text_field :address, class: "form-control", id: :address %>
        <div id='map'></div>
      </div>


    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">

      <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <%= f.label "Цена от" %>
        <input name="event[price][min_price]" value="<%= event.price.try(:min_price) %>" class="form-control" type="number" min="0" />
        <%= f.label "Цена до" %>
        <input name="event[price][max_price]" value="<%= event.price.try(:max_price) %>" class="form-control" type="number" />
        <%= f.label "Тип цены" %>
        <br />
        <%= select_tag :price_types, options_from_collection_for_select(PriceType.all, :id, :name), name: "event[price][price_type_id]", placeholder: "Выберите тип цены" %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <%= f.label "Время проведения" %>
        <%= f.text_field :time, class: "form-control", type: :time %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <%= f.label "Тип отдыха" %>
        <br />
        <%= select_tag :types, options_from_collection_for_select(Type.all, :id, :name, selected: event.types.pluck(:id)), name: "event[types_ids][]", placeholder: "Тип отдыха" %>
      </div>



      <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
        <%= f.label "Дата проведения" %>
        <div id="mdp"></div>
        <input type='hidden' name="event[days]" class="form-control" id="mdp_alt" />
      </div>






    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group text-right">
    <%= f.submit  class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>

<% end %>


<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var dates = <%= event.days.pluck(:date).map{ |d| d.to_s.to_datetime.to_i * 1000 } %>;

    if(dates.length){
      var settings = {
        altField: '#mdp_alt',
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        addDates: dates
      }
    }else{
      var settings = {
        altField: '#mdp_alt',
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
      }
    }
    $('#mdp').multiDatesPicker(settings);

  })  
</script>
```

this is my _error_messages.erb

```
<% if event.errors.any? %>  
<div id="errorExplanation">  
    <h2> В форме обнаружено <%= pluralize(event.errors.count, "ошибка", "ошибки") %>:</h2>  
  <ul>  
  <% event.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>  
    <li><%= msg %></li>  
  <% end %>  
  </ul>  
</div>  
<% end %>
```

what's wrong?

Comment: Can you give an Event model?

Comment: yes, here http://pastie.org/9629150

Comment: Maybe you got an error in update_permalink method, not when you saving your model. Your name is empty.

Comment: thanks, I will try. How do I decide, I will answer you

Comment: What about the controller action, may be you do a redirect when object is not saved instead of rendering the new action? If you do redirect it will not show any errors.

Comment: Try this https://gist.github.com/rmagnum2002/96975a015474df2618a0 but in case this is not working you'll need to see if the problem is in the part where you create a new temp user. Logs for this action would help a lot.

Comment: Can't be blank sounds like a validation message.  I would check your underlying model.  See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html for more details on validations.